# После обновления PHP до версии 7.0 перестали открываться сайты

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, apache2

После обновления *PHP* до версии 7.0 перестали открываться сайты. Сайты на *WordPress*, то есть присутствуют *Apache2*, *Nginx*, *MySQL*. Страницы просто скачиваются на диск.

Comment: Может mod_php не обновился и в итоге апач стартует без поддержки php. смотрите логи веб серверов

Comment: Помимо обновления PHP какие-либо действия выполнялись? Изменения настроек? Как работает PHP, как mod_php или как fastcgi? Покажите настройки httpd.conf/.htaccess, относящиеся к директивам AddHandler и AddType. Есть ли какие-то записи в error.log'е Apache? Если есть - покажите.

Comment: Без лога веб-сервера это вопрос для астрологов и гадалок -> закрыть.

Answer (score -1):

> В зависимости от версии PHP, можно использовать два либо три различных PHP API для доступа к базе данных MySQL. В PHP 5 доступны следующие расширения: устаревшее mysql, mysqli и PDO_MySQL. В PHP 7, устаревшее расширение mysql не доступно и оставлены только два последних.

Comment: Почему вы уверены, что это решит проблему?

Comment: Была такая же ситуация. Сайт работал на mysql, обновился до 7.1 - не работает. Переписал всё на mysqli - всё хорошо. Может ещё Wordpress не тянуть, по крайней мере у битрикса такие проблемы есть. На вервии 5.6 работает, на 7+ ошибки уже при установке

Comment: Но как это связано с вопросом, но который вы оставили ответ?

Comment: "В PHP 7, устаревшее расширение mysql не доступно и оставлены только два последних." - возможно wordpress использует mysql, а не mysqli

Comment: Короче, "возможно на возможно сидит". Это не ответ, а скорее лишь комментарий. Сначала ответ переделать в комментарий, а потом и сам вопрос закрыть.